# How would I get list to match any letters in the last word in the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a word stacking games for kids, then display all the words used, but with any letters within the previous words, so I am stuck with on how to match the last word in the list with the new word.

```
def Word(player, new_word):

  if player == 1:

    t1 = [" "]
    x = input()
    t1.append(x)
    return x
  else:

    t2 = [" "]
    y = input()
    t2.append(y)
    return y
  match(x, y)

def match(x, y):
```

Comment: Your specification is very unclear.  Please show us sample inputs from both players and what output you would expect.  That's the best way to start an app like this.

Comment: Sorry, I am still new to this so I am working from ground up. Like let's say player 1 uses the word apple, then player 2 would have to choose any word that starts with a, p, l, or e. Say player 2 goes with pinecone, then so on and so forth, with all of it being stored in a list or something so at the end of the game it will display all the words both player used.

Comment: OK, so there two important things.  You need a list to keep all of the answers so far, and you can validate the new answer by saying `if thisanswer[0] in previousanswer:`.  Is that enough to get going?